# replace X axis with image in C3js

Tags: javascript, android, c3.js

I am using C3.js chart library for plotting my data.

I need to display a data in little stylish format. The requirement is like, I have to replace the X - axis of the graph with a image on flat mountains. So basically I want to hide default X - axis and replace it with a image. Am not finding any methods to do it.

I am using this as a webview on Android. Is there any trick to do this in either Android or Javascript??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide your x axis elements. To put in an image it will be easier to style the container (styling the SVG element is also possible - you can use a pattern or a filter, but it's easier to style the container)

For example

```
#chart  {
    background: url('img/hills.png') bottom 40px center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 20px;
}

#chart .c3-axis-x path,
#chart .c3-axis-x line {
    display: none;
}
```

where `chart` is the ID of your chart container element.

---

Here is a sample. I've set the image as the JSFiddle logo and set the background color (otherwise you wouldn't see the logo because its all white and transparency)

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a2s8766c/